# Mongo on Linux, From Java App, throwing Exception can't find a master

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am running MongoDb before on Windows and my Java app was connecting perfectly. Now I switch the MongoDb to Linux, and started simply as "./mongod". But whenever I try to connect to Mongo, I got the following exception.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException: can't find a master
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:434)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:209)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:626)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.createIndex(DBApiLayer.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:436)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:515)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndex(DatastoreImpl.java:245)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:310)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:279)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:340)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:333)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your configs are different between linux and windows mongo servers.  Ensure your linux server has joined the replica set properly , and is not firewalled off from the other servers.   All the documentation is here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets

Comment: Nik, Thanks for quick reply. But what if I just want to run MongoDb server a single instance without any replication for the time being, just like I did on windows.

Comment: Ah I see. What are your command line arguments when firing it up on linux?

Comment: I tried, ./mongod AND ./mongod --dbpath /data/db/ they both not work.

Comment: The logs you posted come from your client, not from the mongo server itself.  Chances are that the server config is in fact fine.  What is your connection string etc. you're using in java?

Comment: Hi, Nik.. I figured out the problem and it found to be very ridiculous. Actually, Mongo IP & Port both were wrong, and not accessible in my current local area network. It should, say "host not found" sort of thing, instead saying primary master not found.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a replica master/single problem (as i understood, you are using [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/)).
Before connection, try to change server settings from "localhost:27017" to "127.0.0.1:27017"